# Need help in Solr- Drupal Recruiter

Tags: drupal, solr

Friends,
  First of all I am new to Drupal, Solr. I have installed Drupal Recruiter module and even get Solr installed/configurered. Solr is working at `http://localhost:8983/solr/` means it is responding. I followed all the steps regarding enabling solr modules in Drupal Recruiter.

But Whenever I access search in drupal I am repeatedly getting the following error:

```
"An error occurred while trying to search with Solr: '400' Status: Bad Request."
```

There are couple of solutions given in  stackoverflow, but I am not getting it as I am very much new to both.

Please help me finding where I went wrong.

Thanks in Advance
Dushyant Joshi

Comment: To be able to help you, more information is needed. You could try looking at your solr application logs first to see whether they indicate why it's returning HTTP 400.

Comment: Thanks kekkis, I am getting the following error in the solr logs ,
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: sort param field can't be found: ds_changed at org.apache.solr.search.QueryParsing.parseSort(QueryParsing.java:349) at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getSort(QParser.java:284) at 


And in the front end I get " An error occurred while trying to search with Solr: '400' Status: Bad Request."

Comment: have you installed the solr configiration? You did read the information in the README of Recruiter, didn't you? " The Search API Solr integration provides already some documentation for setting
up a Solr server. See the "Setting up Solr" paragraph at its documentation:

  http://drupalcode.org/project/search_api_solr.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/INSTALL.txt "

Comment: Thanks. I have Solr 4.x. is it not supported by this module? Such is written in the documentation you gave me. if so which version should I install.

Comment: Versions->
solr-spec: 4.0.0.2012.06.25.15.26.16
Recruiter: 7.x-1.0-rc1
OS: ubuntu 12.04
search API Solr search: 1.0, RC 2 (05/23/2012):
And I have "recruiter/profiles/recruiter/modules/search_api_solr/SolrPhpClient" as path for solr API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you indicate that you are using a version of solr (4.0) that is not supported by Search API. The latest non-4.x version is 3.6.1, available for download at http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/solr/3.6.1 .

Update: to anyone coming back to this answer. The problem was that the OP had not used the solr configuration files that come with the Search API Solr module.

Comment: I uninstalled 4.0 and installed Stable 3.6.1 version of solr, however I am getting the same error. Also the the solr is working properly.

Comment: So the question is: have you installed the configuration files for solr that come with Search API solr module?

Comment: The reruitment itself comes with this module, which I found in /profiles/recruiter/modules/search_api_solr/SolrPhpClient. So have I missed anything? I have installed Solr server at [link] http://localhost:8983/solr/  [/link], installed recruiter and get the settings done

Comment: I think that you have missed the part where you were supposed to copy the solr configuration files (schema.xml, solrconfig.xml) from the module to your solr `conf` directory.

Comment: Thanks kekkis for all your help. That was the missing part.It is working properly now.I hope it will help someone. Thanks again.